# Reusing the Database connection object with @vendia/serverless-express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, closures

I want to use my existing ExpressJS code on Lambda functions and the [@vendia/serverless-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vendia/serverless-express) seems to the right package.

I want to reuse the database connections between Lambda invocations. As per AWS docs and other blogs, it can be achieved by storing the connection object outside of the `handler` function. But I am not sure how to do it with the `@vendia/serverless-express` package.

They have the following example code: (can be found in their GH repo [here](https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express/blob/mainline/examples/basic-starter-api-gateway-v2/src/lambda-async-setup.js))

```
const serverlessExpress = require('@vendia/serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')

let serverlessExpressInstance

function asyncTask () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('connected to database'), 1000)
  })
}

async function setup (event, context) {
  const asyncValue = await asyncTask()
  console.log(asyncValue)
  serverlessExpressInstance = serverlessExpress({ app })
  return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context)
}

function handler (event, context) {
  if (serverlessExpressInstance) return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context)

  return setup(event, context)
}

exports.handler = handler
```

I can initialize the connection object in the `asyncTask` function. But, how do I make it available inside my `app`. (Express app) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just figured this out. Use app.set like this:

```
async function setup (event, context) {
  const asyncValue = await asyncTask()
  app.set('asyncValue', asyncValue) 
  serverlessExpressInstance = serverlessExpress({ app })
  return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context)
}
```

with a matching app.get() in the app.js file.